# Add or Append , (comma) after every 16 characters in text file

Tags: c#, hex, append

I have to add or append ,(comma) after every  16 characters in c#.this code is in .txt format.plzz help
some sample code is as follows:

> 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"

i have tried

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string linesFromFile = String.Concat(bin.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
    linesFromFile.Split(',');
    richTextBox1.Text = linesFromFile;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already? Then we can try to help you and see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: This is a very bad question for Stackoverflow. Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "12345678";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        sb.Append(',');
    sb.Append(input[i]);
}
string formatted = sb.ToString();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: thank you so much for your help!! the code is working gr8.

Comment: @toshali You should accept the answer if answer given is working

Answer (score 1):

You can Use StringBuilder for this

```
s = "Your text";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i<s.Length; i++)
{
    char currLetter = s[i];
    result = (i % 16 == 0) ? result.Append(string.Format(",{0}", currLetter)) : result.Append(currLetter);
}
```

Comment: **result.Append(c);** here what reference does 'c' has??

Comment: its the currLetter, I changed the c to currLetter for you to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is:

```
        string result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.ToArray().Length; i++)
        {
            char c = text.ToArray()[i];
            if (i%16 != 0)
                result += c;
            else
                result += "," + c;
        }
```

Comment: You _do_ know that `string` has a `Length` property itself, which should be somewhat faster than copying the whole string to a new array and then asking for the length of the array? Same goes for an indexer.

Comment: I convertet a foreach-loop to a for-loop through my resharper. I didn't controlled the result :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shorter (and not very C#-ish):

```
string x = "that string", y = string.Empty; ; int i = -16;
while ( i < x.Length ) y += x.Skip( i += 16 ).Take( 16 ) + ",";
```

If speed is important you should consider using a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code based on the input...

```
        var input ="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";

        var output = string.Empty;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var c in input)
        {
            count++;
            output += count % 16 == 0 ? "," : c.ToString();
        }

        //Output : 443322115355524,030000000000000,1a000000c0604f0,60624f000000000,ee3e01000000000,50726f626520300,50726f626520300,446174612047726,757000000000000,412d5363616e000,47723a310000000,44656661756c742,4265616d0000000,47617465204d616,6e2028412d53636,6e2900000000000,00790000407b000,807d0000c07f000,008200004084000,80860000c088000,008b0000408d000,808f0000c091000,009400004096000,80980000c09a000,009d0000409f000,80a10000c0a3000,00a6000040a8000,80aa0000c0ac000,00af000040b1000,80b30000c0b5000,00b8000040ba000,80bc0000c0be000,00c1000040c3000,80c50000c0c7000,00ca000040cc000,80ce0000c0d0000,00d3000040d5000,80d70000c0d9000,00dc000040de000,80e00000c0e2000,00e5000040e7000,80e90000c0eb000,00ee000040f0000,80f20000c0f4000,00f7000040f9000,80fb0000c0fd000,000001004002010,80040100c006010,00090100400b010,800d0100c00f010,001201004014010,80160100c018010,001b0100401d010,801f0100c021010,002401004026010,80280100c02a010,002d0100402f010,80310100c033010,003601004038010,803a0100c03c010,003f01004041010,80430100c045010,00480100404a010,804c0100c04e010,005101004053010,80550100c057010,005a0100405c010,805e0100c060010,0
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Output : {0}", output));
```

Comment: From where variable `c` come? :D

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan: Copy paste/edit error. Updated it. Thanks!